# How to see request in fiddler to my site and from my site iis 5

Tags: httpwebrequest, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, fiddler

Hi i have webserver on windows xp iis 5 sp3.
I see logs but thre are only url to my site. But i need see all request informations(headers an body)
For example I go to GMAIl and i click search rss feed(i add my own rss) And gmail need send request to my own webserver
13:01:05 74.125.16.68 GET /9.rss 200 (it send request and i saw log). I want to see all info about request
Headers
Content-type rss
Keep-ALive

ETC...
body

Fiddler dont see this request i have 2 way(safe it with iis or search a good http debugger

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ordinarily Fiddler will show all HTTP traffic going via the Wininet http stack since it tweaks the proxy settings for Wininet when it starts capturing.

In order to route other requests via Fiddler applications need to be manually directed to the Fiddler.

In a .NET application you would use the .config file. Add the following:-

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true">
        <proxy proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" bypassonlocal="False"/>
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Just be sure that Fiddler is capturing when this is enabled and set enabled to false before pausing capture or closing fiddler.

For other applications which may be using the WinHTTP stack use the command:-

```
proxycfg
```

to see what the current proxy config is for WinHTTP.  (Which is likely none). Then:-

```
proxycfg -u
```

to point WinHTTP at the same settings used by WinINET after capture has begun.  Before capture is stopped use:-

```
proxycfg -d
```

to restore direct connection (or use proxycfg -h to learn how to restore the original settings).

Comment: Sorry but i don't see any http requests in fiddler

Comment: Have you made sure filtering is off in Fiddler, for example fiddler can explictely filter out RSS requests so as not to get clogged up with them.  Also you are running fiddler on the machine actually making the requests?  If you see requests on a client machine going to a web server you aren't going to see the subsequent requests that the web server may make to other servers, to do that you need to run fiddler on the server itself.

Comment: i see in fiddler 
POST /mail/?ui=2&ik=ba4ed7ee39&view=cps&q=http%3A%2F%2F217.76.185.140%2F24.rss&cps=r&rt=j HTTP/1.1

This request sent my browser to google it is body
,1240332209980]
,["fl","r",[["8117293465185770465","http://217.76.185.140/24.rss","zzz of the Day","http://\u003cwbr\u003e217.76.185.140/\u003cwbr\u003e24.rss",,

I see in log of my server
16:46:39 74.125.16.68 - W3SVC1 HOUSE 217.76.185.140 80 GET /24.rss - 200 1398 202 HTTP/1.1 217.76.185.140 http://www.google.com/feedfetl

Comment: My server have get request from google but i don't see it in google

Answer (score 1):

Go to tools -> fillder options -> Connections Tab -> Monitor all connections. Good Luck :D.

Comment: That is only useful to when a dialup, VPN or some other PPTP tunnel is up since it enables Fiddler to be the proxy for all such connections rather than just the LAN connection.